# SQL Update each row based on value from other

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I need to do update, but for each row different value.

I have sql like:

```
select c.id as client_id, c.name as c_name, st.id as st_id, st.name as st_name, c.default_store_type_id 
from client c
join store_type st on c.id = st.client_id
```

and now I need for each client do update:

```
UPDATE client c SET c.defaultStoreTypeId = st.id
```

I am trying but with as:

```
with cte (client_id, c_name, st_id, st_name)
    as (
        select c.id as client_id, c.name as c_name, st.id as st_id, st.name as st_name from client c
        join store_type st on c.id = st.client_id
        where c.id not in (9, 12)
        order by c.id
    )
```

But no idea here how to prepare UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE client c
    SET defaultStoreTypeId = st.id
    FROM store_type st 
    WHERE c.id = st.client_id;
```

Comment: hmm but then Ive an error: SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "c" of relation "client" does not exist

Comment: @Baku . . . Don't use an alias in the `set`.  I missed that your expression had this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Postgres `update ... set ... from ... where ...` syntax:

```
update client c
set defaultstoretypeid = s.id
from store_type s
where c.id = s.client_id;
```

Note: Postgres does not accept table prefixes in the `set` clause.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cc3efb7fdd41533f3115501acc8b3a46)**